# Aligning vector layer with basemaps (OSM + Google Satelite) XYZ tiles (from QuickMapServices) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wms, alignment, xyz-tiles

I have this misalignment issue that I could not solve by use of answers to similar questions on GIS Stack Exchange.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed ?

**Background**

- QGIS version 3.24
- I have two vector layers. Both layers' data is for the EPSG 2039 CRS. these vectors, one line and one polygon, are aligned well enough:

[image]

- My base maps are the OSM Standard and Google Satelite XYZ layers provided by the QuickMapServices plugin. My understanding is that EPSG 3857 is the relevant CRS

these two are also aligned:

[image]

- The Project is a **new, blank project** defined to EPSG 3857

The issue: when I add the vector layers I get a misalignment:

[image]

[image]

Using the Reproject processing tool on both vector layers (while setting the target CRS to EPSG 3857) did not help.

UPDATE: Using EPSG 6991 as the project's CRS did not work either.

UPDATE 2 : Test Geopackage with (partial) layers [attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iaWDYd1JpwbM7vJUw3TQarxNkPMwjpbr/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

**session info:**

> QGIS version
> 3.24.1-Tisler QGIS code revision 5709b82461 Qt version
> 5.15.2 Python version
> 3.9.5 GDAL/OGR version
> 3.4.2 PROJ version
> 9.0.0 EPSG Registry database version () GEOS version
> 3.10.2-CAPI-1.16.0 SQLite version
> 3.38.1 PDAL version
> 2.3.0 PostgreSQL client version unknown SpatiaLite version
> 5.0.1 QWT version
> 6.1.3 QScintilla2 version
> 2.11.5 OS version Windows 10 Version 2009
>
> Active Python plugins israeli_opendata_loader
> 1.0.0 quick_map_services
> 0.19.29 XYZHubConnector
> 1.9.2 db_manager
> 0.1.20 grassprovider
> 2.12.99 MetaSearch
> 0.3.6 processing
> 2.12.99

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74533/why-is-there-a-difference-between-using-epsg-and-using-basic-code

Comment: I don't see how these two are related, despite both cases involving the same CRS. I wasn't trying to understand why selecting EPSG vs. coding makes a difference. Can you clarify the reason for marking this as related ? thanks